# Adding Jetbrains Compose to Kotlin/JVM Desktop build.gradle (Groovy)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

With no sample on how to add compose (desktop, no KMP involved) to build.gradle (**Groovy**) file I'm not sure which and how to add the dependencies required:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "org.jetbrains.compose" version "1.5.11"
}
```

however, in build.gradle.kts it's similar to:

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

...

repositories {
    ...
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}
```

Basically, how to convert the **kts** version to Groovy one?